# Siri freezes on screen when opening

Tags: performance, siri

This issue occurred when i said launch finder, 2 seconds later it froze permanently on the screen. I tried to reboot the macbook 2012, but when i launched siri again it froze, stuck on the screen. Tried safe mode, but still nothing. I really need help.
Version of macos is macos high sierra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reinstall macOS by booting with <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> on boot up. Then press 'Reinstall macOS' and follow the instructions.

See this Apple support article for more information: https://support.apple.com/T204904